# Android: How to access/share a Activity bound service with another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-service, android-fragmentactivity

I have a main Activity that's happily been working with a Service I created for a while now. Recently I've had to add a DialogFragment to my app and although its working nicely as well, I now need to make a call to my Service and pass along more than the usual Intent type strings. Basically I need to pass an array of Bitmaps to the Service, and I don't think it's reasonable to try and stuff them into an Intent.

So I was hoping, without luck so far, that I could bind to the service while the DialogFragement is open so I can make a direct method call to the Service.

Is there any way to do this? So I have to copy the entire ServiceConnection class and bind to it from onStart()? I figured there must be a less messy way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no code, I assume that your `DialogFragment` serves to capture some kind of input from the user (Yes/No or something similar), as most dialogs do. If this is the case, then you can simply return the input back to the calling `Activity` and make a call to the `Service` based on this input. Another question is where to the `Bitmaps` come from? Passing an array of `Bitmaps` from an `Activity` to a `Service` doesn't seem a good decision for me, you should probably consider moving the `Bitmap` retrieving logic to the `Service` itself, whether the `Bitmaps` come from the network or from resources.

Most part of my answer is based on assumptions about the design of your application, so if those assumptions go wrong you can post some code or add a broader description of your app and I'll be glad to review my answer.

Comment: I am using a DialogFragment that has Save and Cancel buttons. There's a camera button that starts the built-in camera, and the DialogFragment implements the onActivityResult(). The DialogFragment has a layout that allows for multiple "attachment" of images. The "Save" button actions trying to get the bitmaps to the Service. Right now I've decided to save the images to disk (which is only necessary for my use case, not because I want to save them) so I can send an Intent that contains the image filenames/paths. You get the check for suggesting moving the retreive to the Service.

Comment: Ya and the sdcard approach works great actually. Passing the path/file via Intent avoids having to make a copy of it (Base64 encode, then pass it through the Intent framework) which is why I wanted to originally bind to the Service and make a direct method call.